# фон svg через js

Tags: javascript, html, css, вёрстка, svg

Есть блок с `svg`, в котором меняется цвет при клике на блок.
http://u558049.s54.wh1.su/metalli/app2/hestiya.html вот на этой странице.

Вот скрипт, который это делает:

```
  $('.color__tabs_items .standart .color > div').on('click',function(){
    let color = $(this).css('background-color');
    console.log(color);
    $('.color__tabs_items .standart .color > div').removeClass('active');
    let parents_svg = $('.svg_color').css('fill', color);
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
```

Мне надо добавить возможность помимо цвета добавлять на фон изображение.

Что я уже пробовал:

- Я создал паттерн, присвоил ему `ID`.
- `background-color` сменил на `background`.
- Прописал вместо цвета `background: url(#idpaterna);`

И в `fill` почему то `"url(#idpaterna)"` не передалось.

И как оказалось, там грузится не просто цвет `html`, а где-то он преобразовывается в `rgb`.

[image: наглядный пример что я хочу получить]

Comment: плохо понятно что надо

Comment: нужно не только цвет но и изображение накладывать на svg как на скрине.

Comment: @Hard User У вас изображение png, svg, которое вы хотите добавлять вместе со цветом? Добавьте сюда ссылку на него или код svg иконки. Чтобы можно было, что-то конкретно пробовать

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Я же ссылку на сайт бросил и могу фтп дать.

Comment: @Alexandr_TT там коректируется непосредственно svg который в коде прямо.

Comment: @Hard User  то есть вам неохота самому поискать, тот кусок кода svg, который меняется, предлагаете людям поискать на чужом сайте. Вам же легче это сделать, раз занимаетесь этим сайтом

Comment: 404 File not found.

Comment: код html css есть ?